# How can I get the locator value from a webelement?

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

I would like to get the value of the selector used from a selenium webelement in javascript.

If I have the object:
`var el = browser.driver.findElement(by.id('testEl'));`

I'd like to get that text 'testEl' and use it elsewhere. I don't care what the selector type is(by id, by css, etc.), just what the text is.

In protractor, I could do this:
`console.log(el.locator().value);`
This would return the text 'testEl'.

But with just selenium non-protractor selectors, I am told that .value() is not a function.

Is there any way to pull this locator/selector value out?

**EDIT:**

The goal: Grab the locator text from a selenium webElement

The use: For functions like getVisibleElement

The situation: Working against a page where there can be an unknown number of elements of a certain selector, some hidden and some not(but an area above them hidden, no hidden tag on this particular portion of the element to work with), and I'd like to get just the visible ones.

In protractor:

```
function getVisibleElementByPageObject(protractorWebElement){
    var allElementsOfSelector = element.all(by.css(protractorWebElement.locator().value));
    var displayedElement = allElementsOfSelector .filter(function(elem) {
        return elem.isDisplayed('cannot find' + ' ' + protractorWebElement.locator().value);
    }).first();
    return displayedElement ;
}

var exampleEl = $('[name="test"]');
var visibleExampleEl = getVisibleElementByPageObject(exampleEl);
```

I'd like to get the locator so that if I ever change what the selector is, I would need to only change it in one place - the page object where the element is declared.

I can use a var to store the string and pass that along anytime I declare an element or try to use something like the above, but that just means using a new standard of setting up page objects. It would be very convenient to access the locator in selenium like protractor does above.

Comment: Note that you can still use `protractor` for non-angular sites - it's just a wrapper around selenium javascript bindings.

Comment: Hey @alecxe! I am actually running this all in protractor. For the non-angular portions of the site, I am having to use selenium selectors, as performing actions on a protractor selector would require angular. The selenium web elements dont have the locator().value option so far as I can tell.

Comment: From what I recall, you don't have to use `driver.findElement()` and can continue to use protractor's `element()` on non-angular sites..the only important difference is the synchronization which is turned off.

Comment: Anytime I try to use a protractor element on this page, I get errors about `Angular could not be found on the window.` Selenium elements didnt have this issue, so I've been using them.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just store the locator in a variable and reuse it that way?

Comment: Could you upload the html for this?

Comment: I've added some extra details to the main post.

I can store the locator in a variable, it is just one more thing to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to get the locator from the webElement, you should already have it the first time you use it to find the element. If your page objects aren't already set up that way, you're doing it wrong.

In webdriver.js, they show this example:

```
*     var link = element.findElement(firstVisibleLink);
*
*     function firstVisibleLink(element) {
*       var links = element.findElements(By.tagName('a'));
*       return webdriver.promise.filter(links, function(link) {
*         return links.isDisplayed();
*       }).then(function(visibleLinks) {
*         return visibleLinks[0];
*       });
*     }
```

So you should be able to:

```
var firstElement = function(locator) {
    return browser.driver.findElement(locator);
};
var firstVisible = function(locator) {
    var elements = browser.driver.findElements(locator);
    return browser.driver.promise.filter(elements, function(el) {
        return el.isDisplayed();
    }).then(function(visibleElements) {
        return visibleElements[0];
    });
};

var testLocator = by.css('[name="test"]');
var E1 = firstElement(testLocator);
var E1v = firstVisible(testLocator);
```